# Installing FileReaderSync in Angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, filereader

How do I install `FileReaderSync` in Angular2?

It appears in the file `node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.webworker.d.ts` but not can use it.

The `FileReader` I can use it without having to import anything.

I need to do something different with FileReaderSync?

`error TS2304: Cannot find name 'FileReaderSync'.`

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue few months ago, the solution was to write custom typings.

main.bowser.d.ts

```
interface FileReaderSync {
  readAsArrayBuffer(blob: Blob): any;
  readAsBinaryString(blob: Blob): void;
  readAsDataURL(blob: Blob): string;
  readAsText(blob: Blob, encoding?: string): string;
}

declare var FileReaderSync: {
  prototype: FileReaderSync;
  new(): FileReaderSync;
};
```

and include them when you bootstrap angular2

```
// <reference path="./main.browser.d.ts" />
```

I wrote an article about this just now :D
http://icode.co/angular2/php/2016/12/21/async-file-streaming-from-JS-to-PHP-WebWorkers.html