# how to import FileReaderSync with angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to read a file with FileReaderSync

```
let reader = new FileReaderSync();
let result_base64 = reader.readAsDataURL(file);
```

But I have the following error message

```
Cannot find name 'FileReaderSync'.
```

I don't know how import FileReaderSync **with angular 8**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Installing FileReaderSync in Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39807671/installing-filereadersync-in-angular2)

Comment: No, this is the way with angular 2, but it is not the same thing with angular 8. I already tried to do it in the similar way without success

Answer (score -1):

somebody gave me the solution on another forum. The missing part was to add onloadend facility

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
 
@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = "Angular";
 
  public imageFile: any;
  filesToCropp = [];
  reader = new FileReader();
 
  uploadFile(events: any) {
    let that = this;
    for (const event of events) {
      that.reader.onload = (event: any) => {
        that.filesToCropp.push(event.target.result);
      };
      that.reader.readAsDataURL(event);
    }
    this.reader.onloadend = (event: any) => {
      console.log(that.filesToCropp);      // filesToCropp  contient un tableau (en base64) avec tous les fichiers que l'on a sélectionnés 
    };
  }
}
```